# nopCommerce assembly dont find dll reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dll, telerik, nopcommerce

Im having some serous issues with a .dll not being found in Nop.Core.dll (i think)
the dll message the PluginManager.cs writes in the output in VS12 is as follows:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.Mvc, Version=2012.2.607.340, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=29ac1a93ec063d92' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Ive added the right version of Telerik.Web.Mvc to the Nop.Core lib and built a new .dll but the issue still remains.
Ive also checked for cached .dlls in th GAC but nothing.

The issue occured after a restart of VS12 so there´s smt weird going on here. Ive tried disabling/enabeling auto update nuget on build (as i thought that it might be fetching some new dlls that might create a conflict) but nothing.

I do see that the Solution is running .net 4.5 but the Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll target framework is :

```
TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0", FrameworkDisplayName=".NET Framework 4")].
```

Can this cause some dll´s to not find Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll?

As im new to nopCommerce im kinda lost at this point. What am i doing wrong here? =)

/seb

Edit:

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have non-corrupted **Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll** in your bin folder (download one that comes with nopcommerce and overwrite it to be sure)
2. This issue may be caused by a plugin that has wrong reference. If you have any custom/old plugins try removing them or readd their reference and recompile.

Current version in 3.10 is **2013.2.611.340** while you have reference to **2012.2.607.340**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the above steps before i posted but it didnt solve my problem (even tho in many cases it is the correct answer). it turns out that somehow my Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll got modified somehow when i opened the solution file in VS12. Might have been Git och Nuget or smt, not sure yet. I have a temp solution for this and this solution is: Open the solution in VS12 -> revert the Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll to the one that is in the versioncontrol -> build and run. Its a hack but it works for now. :)

Comment: Maybe the Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll was blocked.  You can unblock it by right clicking on it in Explorer and going to the Properties.